# Can a SORU operator commit to multiple rollups on the same deposit?

Tags: smart-rollup

From https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/smart_rollups.html#commitments

> Notice that, to publish a commitment, an operator must provide a deposit of 10,000 tez.

Does that mean that once I've made my 10K tez deposit, I can make commitments on *any* rollup, or do I need 10K tez for each rollup I'm making commitments on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to lock 10k tez bond for each smart rollup you want to publish commitments for. For example, this account committed to 3 different rollups ([one](https://mumbainet.tzkt.io/oo3Wt8JFN1TLpxdviZpAnnbPbc41tG11Tx17Mq9Zz5ENU3UMNih/1647), [two](https://mumbainet.tzkt.io/onn3GAfp66r4wQcqsYvWfMX7ZLj64FbaMVG8L4ye1hWG7E3bvmU/1798), [three](https://mumbainet.tzkt.io/op9PHJzhDFeUDo5VT9YXj4L3ekE7DYd9hWP8W8sofRceoEAwBNY/1858)) and now it has [30k tez locked](https://mumbainet.tzkt.io/tz1fepBiYL6EDuNMXU2FwefgAGxVmRxVSRQy/info/) in total.

Comment: Thanks. Also, for the curious, I just found the source https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/832bd97512518d63ed7052bdff7618f04a2dc0fd/src/proto_016_PtMumbai/lib_protocol/sc_rollup_stake_storage.ml#L559-567